# How to make a button appear only when input is focused

Tags: html, css, vue.js

here is my HTML:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="id!==undefined">
      <strong>ID</strong>
      <input
        id="id"
        v-model="id"
        type="text"
        readonly
      >
        <button
          type="button"
          @click="doCopy"
        >
          <font-awesome-icon :icon="copyIcon" />
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
<style scoped>
  input {
    margin-left: 2px;
    border: none;
  }
  input:focus {
    border: 1px solid #21abd4;
    border-radius: 5px;
    button: visible;
  }
  button {
    visibility: hidden;
    border: none;
    background: none;
  }

</style>
```

I want something that will only display button when the input is focused, tried a number of approaches like trying to call the button from within. input:focus but the IDE complains of this. Trying to pair input:focus + button  but that is also not working so not sure how to chain both together :(

Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the CSS [adjacent sibling selector (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to accomplish this:

```
   input:focus + button
```

to select a `button` that comes immediately after an `input:focus` element.

```css
input {
  margin-left: 2px;
  border: none;
}

input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #21abd4;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input:focus + button {
  visibility: visible;
}

button {
  visibility: hidden;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div >
    <strong>ID</strong>
    <input id="id" type="text" readonly />
    <button type="button" @click="doCopy">
      Copy 
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

That said, there would also be ways in Vue to update a shared state, and set the visibility of the button based on the state of the input.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done fairly easily with jQuery:

```js
$("input").focus(function() {
  $("button").css("visibility", "visible");
});

$("input").focusout(function() {
  $("button").css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

```css
button {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/><button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: where would this go in a vue file?

Comment: @Will I've never used Vue, sorry.