# Why button using 'focus-within' is not working on iOS

Tags: html, css, svelte

I need a hidden delete button to appear and work when a input is focused using markup and CSS in Svelte.

I got it all working in browsers for OS X and Raspberry Pi OS (Chrome, Chromium, Safari and Firefox). [Click here to see it](https://2-dos.netlify.app/).

The problem is that the button appears but is not working in any of my iOS browsers (Safari or Firefox). Nothing is happening when the delete button is clicked.

I've tried following:

- [focus-within works on Android browser but not iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66477748/focus-within-works-on-android-browser-but-not-ios)
- [How to make a button appear only when input is focused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57930783/how-to-make-a-button-appear-only-when-input-is-focused)

Here is the markup...

```
<form>
    {#if $todos}
        {#each $todos as { data }, i}
            <div id="todo">
                <button on:click|preventDefault={remove(i + 1)}></button>
                <input
                    bind:value={data.name}
                    on:change={update(i + 1)}
                    size={data.name.length}
                    maxlength="35"
                />
            </div>
        {/each}
    {/if}
</form>
```

...and here is the styling...

```
<style>
    form,
    div {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    input {
        border-style: none;
        font-size: 2vh;
    }

    input:focus {
        border-style: solid;
    }

    button {
        visibility: hidden;
        font-size: 2vh;
    }

    #todo:focus-within button {
        visibility: visible;
    }
</style>
```

```css
form,
div {
  display: flex;
}

form {
  width: 100vw;
}

input {
  border-style: none;
}

input:focus {
  border-style: solid;
}

button {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#todo1:focus-within button {
  visibility: visible;
}

#todo2:focus-within button {
  visibility: visible;
}

#todo3:focus-within button {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>Svelte + Node.js API</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>To Do</h1>
  <form>
    <div id="todo1">
      <button onclick="alert('Input deleted')"></button>
      <input value="Try it out">
    </div>
    <div id="todo2">
      <button onclick="alert('Input deleted')"></button>
      <input value="Fix the bug">
    </div>
    <div id="todo3">
      <button onclick="alert('Input deleted')"></button>
      <input value="Celebrate">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little bit of debugging, it turns out, that by attempting to click on a button, you actually click on a `<div>` element itself:

```js
function setLogs(element) {
  element.addEventListener("focus", () => {
    console.log("focus", element);
  });

  element.addEventListener("blur", () => {
    console.log("blur", element);
  });

  for (const child of element.children)
    setLogs(child);
}

setLogs(document.body);
```

```css
button {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#todo:focus-within button {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>To Do</h1>
  <form onsubmit="return false">
    <div id="todo">
      <button onclick="console.log('Input deleted')"></button>
      <input value="Try it out">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The reason for that is that focusing on one element after another one is a two-part event: first, you remove focus from the first element, then you set focus to the second one. By clicking on the area with the button, you remove the focus from the `<input>` element. Removed focus leads to `:focus-within` stop being applicable, and the button becomes hidden again. So, when the second part of the clicking event happens, there's no button there anymore, and the click is applied to the next element in the stack – the `<div>` element itself.

Comment: I like your answer but why it works in other browsers than for iOS? Any solution?

Comment: I am honestly not sure why this works in other browsers (I've tried Chrome); to me, Apple's implementation or more consistent, but Google's implementation is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using "opacity" instead of "visibility" which seems to work also with iOS browsers.

```css
form,
div {
  display: flex;
}

form {
  width: 100vw;
}

input {
  border-style: none;
}

input:focus {
  border-style: solid;
}

button {
  opacity: 0;
}

#todo1:focus-within button {
  opacity: 1;
}

#todo2:focus-within button {
  opacity: 1;
}

#todo3:focus-within button {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>Svelte + Node.js API</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>To Do</h1>
  <form>
    <div id="todo1">
      <button onclick="alert('Input deleted')"></button>
      <input value="Try it out">
    </div>
    <div id="todo2">
      <button onclick="alert('Input deleted')"></button>
      <input value="Fix the bug">
    </div>
    <div id="todo3">
      <button onclick="alert('Input deleted')"></button>
      <input value="Celebrate">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the `mousedown` event instead of `click` and you'll be able to handle the event before iOS changes focus.

It's more standard practice to trigger an event on `click` but in this case it seems to be the only workaround to iOS's behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Tried it but unfortunately it broke my program. "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

Comment: A network error is unrelated to this problem though, so it is more to do with your specific app than getting the button to trigger on ios